# Wrong input shape to neural network layer

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to classify handwritten digits using the MNIST dataset to train my model. My model trained successfully and hit an accuracy of 98.9%. But when I try and input a custom image it shows me the following error :

```
Error when checking : expected conv2d_4_input to have shape (None, 28, 28, 1) but got array with shape (1, 1, 28, 28)
```

This is the first convolutional layer i.e. the input layer.
What can I do to resolve this issue ?
This is my Convolutional Neural Network :

```
conv_model = Sequential()
conv_model.add(Conv2D(filters, kernel_size[0], input_shape=(28 , 28 , 1)))
conv_model.add(Activation(act))
conv_model.add(Conv2D(filters, kernel_size[0]))
conv_model.add(Activation(act))
conv_model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
conv_model.add(Dropout(0.25))
conv_model.add(Flatten())
conv_model.add(Dense(128))
conv_model.add(Activation(act))
conv_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
conv_model.add(Dense(10))
conv_model.add(Activation('softmax'))
#conv_model.summary()
```

Compilation Details :

```
conv_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

COMPLETE SOURCE CODE :
https://github.com/tanmay-edgelord/HandwrittenDigitRecognition

The image :
[image]
If any further details are required please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty straight:

- Your first layer is expecting data with shape (None, 28, 28, 1), where "None" can be any number (it's the batch size, how many examples you have).
- Your data on the other hand has shape (1, 1, 28, 28).

The confusion seems to me a common one: Keras puts the channels at the last dimension, and your data has the channels in the first.

**Solution:**

Just reshape your data in the correct format: (1, 28, 28, 1).

---

But are you trying to give that entire image to the model??? If so, it won't work very well, it's expecting images with 28 x 28 pixels.

You will have to separate each number in a different 28 x 28 image. And you must take into account the possibility of your image being inverted in terms of what is black and what is white. Usually the MNIST data has a black background (0 values) with a white number (1 values).

Comment: I am resizing the image using the cv2.resize function for every contour that the function cv2.contour finds (every contours will be a digit in this case).  Also I tried inputting the size 1 , 28 , 28 , 1 to cv2.resize but it gave me the error that only 2 arguments are expected. I highly recommend that you checkout the performRecognition code

Comment: I am using tensorflow on the backend

Comment: Use cv2 normally and reshape the result later. Reshape `roi` after it's ready, just before using `model.predict`. If `roi` is a numpy array, it's as easy as `roi = roi.reshape((1,28,28,1))`. If not, make it be a numpy array: `roi = np.array(roi)`.

Comment: Yes I did that it worked fine without roi = np.array(roi)

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved by passing it to the reshape function with the correct input size

```
roi2 = roi.reshape(1,28,28,1)
```